# How to push array value of the title in select ng repeat dropdown array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" type="text" name="productname" ng-model="prod" ng-change="GetSubCategory(prod)/>
<option value="">select</option>
<option ng-repeat="pro in ProductsArray" value="{{pro}}">{{pro.ProductName}}</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" type="text" name="subprod" ng-model="subprod" />
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="subpro in SubProductsArray" value="{{subpro}}">{{subpro.SProductName}}</option>
</select>

<button type="sumbit" ng-click="add_po_Product()" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="add"></button>
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.products = [];
$scope.prod = [];
$scope.subprod = [];

$scope.add_po_Product = function() {       
    $scope.prod = JSON.parse($scope.prod);
    $scope.subprod = JSON.parse($scope.subprod);
    $scope.products.push({  
        Pid: $scope.prod.ProductId,
        PName: $scope.prod.ProductName,
        SPid: $scope.subprod.SProductId,
        SPName: $scope.subprod.SProductName,
    });
    $scope.prod= '';
    $scope.subprod= '';
}
```

Here I am loading `SubProductsArray` using `ng-change="GetSubCategory()"`. But I am unable to push the values into array. 
Is there any mistake I did?

Comment: you are pushing to `products` array, whereas your ng-repeat arrays are: `ProductsArray` and `SubProductsArray`. Are you sure you are using the right ones?

Comment: yes. where i am pushing single 
    $scope.prod = JSON.parse($scope.prod);
it is working. while passing mutiple values it's not woking

Comment: Why don't you provide a jsfiddle or Plunker to get quick help?